# MySQL MAX foreach day

Tags: mysql

I have the following table with measured values:

```
           datetime | water |  air | conductivity | ...
2021-07-17 16:44:39 |  13,9 | 18,6 |          357 | ...
```

I am currently querying the values ​​for a period of time:

```
SELECT * FROM kn1 WHERE datetime > TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)) ORDER BY datetime
```

Now I don't want to get every value, just the highest value of each day.
In general, I can query the highest value through

```
SELECT MAX(water) FROM kn1 WHERE datetime > TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)) ORDER BY datetime
```

But this way I get the highest value for the entire period. But I would like to get the highest value for each day in the period.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime), MAX(water)
FROM kn1
WHERE datetime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month)
GROUP BY DATE(datetime);
```

Note that I modified the `WHERE` clause to simplify it.  Presumably, you don't date about the current *time*, just the date, so this uses the current date.  Second, there is no need for `TIMESTAMP`, and third, I find interval arithmetic to be simpler without additional functions.